# How to prevent pandas pivot from discarding other columns that are not in the pivot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I have a df that looks like this:

```
id   FieldTitle  Value  number
1     fname       aaa    12
2     lname       bbb    12
```

When I run this line of code:

```
pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Id', columns='FieldTitle', values='Value', aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```

The df that is left is:

```
fname    lname
aaa        bbb
```

Why is pivot causing the other columns to disappear and how do I fix it?

The df should look like this:

```
id   fname  lname  number
1     aaa    bbb    12
```

Comment: I don't get that output at all

Comment: @user3483203 updated the df

Comment: Still don't get the output you say you're getting.

Comment: @user3483203 I dont  have any other way to explain it. pivot_table is dropping columns that are not being pivoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your example here, I think adding static columns to the index will solve your issue

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2], "FieldTitle":["fname", "lname"], "Value":["aaa", "bbb"], "number":[12,12]})
pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["number"], columns='FieldTitle', values=['Value'], aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```

You may then need to rename the columns as you'll have a multi-index.

Alternatively consider pivoting, dropping duplicate columns from your original dataset and then merging back together with the result

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am still getting same results only coluumns from the pivot, with the word 'value' added to the coliumn names.

Comment: Have you run the snippet above? And in your real world example have you added your static columns to the index?

Comment: I have run the above snippet, still getting the same results. Could you please show me how to add the static columns into the index?

Comment: Where the index is set to `number` how can I set it to the static columns?

Comment: What I'm saying is, have you tried feeding in a list of all of your stationary columns into `index=[YOUR_STATIONARY_COLUMNS]`